# How to redirect port for GCP compute instance using NAT rule for VPC Firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, gcp-vpc-firewall

I have deployed Apache Tomcat 9 to the GCP compute instance (created via cloud console with tags: `tomcat-web-host`,`http-server` and `https-server`) which works fine on default ports 8080 and 8443 (created in VPC Firewall via terraform below).

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "tomcat-on-vm" {
  project     = var.project_id
  name        = "tomcat-on-vm"
  network     = var.network
  description = "Creates firewall rule targeting tagged instances"

  allow {
    protocol  = "tcp"
    ports     = ["8080", "8443"]
  }

  target_tags = ["tomcat-web-host"]
}
```

Now I'm trying to map HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) to 8080 and 8443 in a way which I will do the same way on-prem NAT as:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -o eth0 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080;
```

but that will take no effect (port 80 still not reachable). How can  I do the same but in GCP VPC firewall for a compute instance?

Comment: How is this question related to Google Cloud or Google Cloud VPC Firewalls? Your question is about IPTables.

Comment: @JohnHanley Because of above command not taking any effect in the compute instance as well `firewall-cmd --list-all` will not return anything for that VM so I expect that needs to be done on GCP VPC Firewall or Cloud NAT. Also when I do open ports for Tomcat I did that in GCP VPC Firewall as well.

Comment: Then modify your question to be about VPC Firewalls. Show what you have configured, what tests you are running, and error messages. For example, Compute Engine supports network tags. What you have defined to automatically attach VPC Firewall rules? The better you present the problem, the easier to get a good answer.

Comment: @JohnHanley Question is about `NAT mapping in GCP VPC firewall` so it is about VPC Firewall. I. have updated OP with more info how VM got tagged with VPC Firewall for both default ports.

Comment: I am trying to help you. Repeating the phrase **NAT mapping in GCP VPC firewall** is not helpful. What mapping, what NAT, etc? You might think something is obvious, but it is not in this case. If someone who has extensive experience in this area does not understand your question and problem what do you expect? I am asking for details so that a **good** answer can be created.

Comment: @JohnHanley OK. I have changed title from a generic to more granular.

Comment: Cloud NAT has nothing to do with VPC firewalls. If your compute engine instance has a public IP address, then Cloud NAT does nothing for you. If your VM is configured with only a private IP address, then Cloud NAT provides **outbound** internet connectivity and not inbound connectivity. Again, the problem that you have is not clearly defined by your question. You state **Now I'm trying to map HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) to 8080 and 8443**. Why? What are you trying to accomplish? How does that statement have anything to do with Cloud NAT?

Comment: If your objective is to receive public Internet traffic on ports 80 and 443 to the VM and then remap that traffic internally to ports 8080 and 8443, then configure a VPC firewall ingress rule allowing ports 80 and 443. Then configure an IP tables rule remapping 80 -> 8080 and 443 -> 8443.

Comment: After you modified the question, you included Terraform HCL. Change the HCL to allow 80 and 443. Then you will need to create a startup script to perform the IP Tables rule creation.

Comment: @JohnHanley Compute instance comes with the 80 and 443 by default if you will check them in during creation so that is done w/o terraform and it tagged as `http-server` and `https-server`. The iptables part, as I have put in the OP, is not working as I have expected that is why I have posted my question.

Comment: @JohnHanley Why I'm mapping 80 to 8080 and 443 to 8443? You are Linux guy so your should to know why it is done for Apache Tomcat to get it to work correctly w/o modifying authback. But that doesn't matter - I want be able to map any port. And as I said - solution from the OP works fine on-prem but for some reason doesn't work on compute instance and my question is why and how it should be done correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Google Support response my approach will not work there and an external load balancer may be solution to that problem

> The GCP doesn't implement unsolicited inbound connections from the
> internet. DNAT is only performed for packets that arrive as responses
> to outbound packets.
>
> Going with your case description, I understand what you are doing can
> be achieved via Load Balancer, for which you can setup LB to listen on
> frontend port 80 and send traffic on backend port 8080.